# An error occurred during service master key initialization (sql error log)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, migration, encryption, system-databases

I have migrated sql server 2017 to new hardware. The sql error log shows following error log whenever the sql server service is restarted.

`An error occurred during service master key initialization`

I recently restored the master, msdb databases from older hardware to new hardware. Linked servers don't work for example if I try to create a linked server it gives following error: `An error occurred during service master key decryption`. Same error when creating credential.

I understand this is something related to the SMK (service master key).

Doesn't the SMK already exist since I have restored the master database (assuming the SMK is held in the master db)?

Why am I getting these errors? Why can I not create/access linked sever and credentials?

Comment: Are you using the same service account? If not, you need to backup and restore the service master key separately because it's protected by the service account.

Comment: Using different service account. Should I restore the SMK before or after restoring the master and msdb?

Comment: Restore the SMK after restoring master. That will allow decrypting of the secrets it protects.

Comment: MSDN says - `When the service master key is restored, SQL Server decrypts all the keys and secrets that have been encrypted with the current service master key, and then encrypts them with the service master key loaded from the backup file.` - after restoring the master db, and since my sql service account is different, how will it be able to decrypt the keys and secrets that have been encrypted with the current service master key

Comment: When you backup the SMK from the source, you provide a password to protect it (`ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD` clause). The same password is specified during the SMK restore (`DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD` clause), which allows decryption of existing secrets. The secrets are then re-encrypted using the restored SMK and the SMK is protected with the SQL Server service account.

Comment: Any documentation for this please? Because doc I am reading says that first it tries to decrypt keys/secrets with the existing SMK (and a different svc account won't be able to decrypt the existing SMK).

Comment: We are reading the [same documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-service-master-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks). The "existing SMK" is one restored, not the one before the restore (which cannot be decrypted due to the service account change).

Comment: Highly respect your knowledge but then I strongly feel that `current service master key` is the one from restored master db's SMK  (which cannot be decrypted). I'm just not able to get my head around fact that current key means the SMK from the backup file. I have read the above quote couple of times and it's still not clear.